# Load balancing Kubernetes cluster across two different cloud providers

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, google-compute-engine, kubernetes

I want to create one kubernetes cluster on GCE and another one on AWS, both running the same application.

What would be the best way to load balance across them?

Answer (score 2):

You can deploy the same application on both platforms, expose it via an L3 / L7 service and then create a DNS entry that includes the public IP for each cluster.

If you want more than just round-robin load balancing, you can use a service like [Route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/) to do latency or geo based routing and also add DNS health checks.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on how to perform these steps - exposing via L3/L7 service and then creating a DNS entry?

Comment: You can create an L3 service by running `kubectl expose` on a deployment / replica set / replication controller and it will create a service for the object and associate an external IP with it. You can create an L7 service using an `ingress` object which will also get an external IP. Once you have an external IP on both clusters, you can create a DNS entry that maps a human name to both of the public IP addresses.